# Unable to do export-csv from an empty .txt file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a csv file from an empty text file.The csv file should get created with only headers as no data present in text file but my code is creating a complete blank csv file without header.Anything missing in below code ?

```
 import-csv -Path "C:\Powershell-Work\EmtyTest.txt" -Header Date,Time,'R Site',Status,Comments |
 Select-Object 'Process Date',Date,Time,'R Site',Status,Comments| 
 Export-csv -path "C:\Powershell-Work\EmtyTest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `EmtyTest.txt` is a blank file `Import-CSV` is producing an empty array.

As the source data is empty your output file will also be blank.

A CSV File is just text, so you can just create it from a string:

```
'"Process Date","Date","Time","R Site","Status","Comments"' | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Powershell-Work\EmtyTest.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there isn't any need for importing from a blank text file, as you can create a `csv` on the fly with your desired headers. One of the many ways of doing it would be creating a `PSObject` and adding the `headers` as `PropertyName` while you can put the `values` as `NULL`. Below is an example -

```
$csvContents = @()

$row = New-Object System.Object # Create an object to append to the array
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Process Date" -value ""
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -value ""
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Time" -value ""
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "R Site" -value ""
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -value ""
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Comments" -value ""

$csvContents += $row

$csvContents | Export-CSV -Path C:\Powershell-Work\EmtyTest.csv -NoTypeInformation
```